# Is it safe to wrap windows header file in a namespace?

Tags: c++, windows

The following code can compile

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
namespace win32 {
    extern "C" {
        #include <windows.h>
    }
}
int main()
{
    char buf[MAX_PATH]{};
    win32::GetModuleFileNameA(nullptr, buf, std::extent_v<decltype(buf)> - 1);
    std::cout << buf;

    return 0;
}
```

But I'm not confident if it is safe to wrap windows header files in this way. Can I always do this on windows programming?

Comment: Does it actually compile? Doesn't on my system.

Comment: It does compile even with no warning, both by clang and msvc

Comment: By including part of the STL, you're skipping most of the #includes inside windows.h. This can work with one SDK version but fail with another. It's a hack.

Comment: Generally, no.   `windows.h` (or headers it includes directly or indirectly) declares functions, types, named values, etc that are not defined within any namespace (since they're usable from C).   You might get lucky with some compilers, but the more likely outcome is a failed build, since a call of (say) `win32::something()` won't resolve to a call of the `something()` that is declared in `windows.h`

Comment: Windows has a lot of `#defines` so you will never properly confine it.

Answer (score 3):

#### No.

The Windows header is not designed to be encapsulated in any way.

Unless you are writing a Win32 application that uses the Windows API extensively for its basic function, you should limit its use to source code separated from the rest of your program’s source code. For example:

`platform.hpp`

```
#include <string>

namespace platform
{
  std::string GetExeFileName();
}
```

`platform.cpp`

```
#include "platform.hpp"
#include <windows.h>

std:string platform::GetExeFileName()
{
  char buf[MAX_PATH];
  DWORD ok = GetModuleFileNameA( NULL, buf, MAX_PATH );
  return ok ? buf : "";
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "platform.hpp"

int main()
{
  std::cout << platform::GetExeFileName() << "\n";
}
```